# Two different header files one implementation file

Tags: iphone, xcode, header

Header Files: SettingsVC.h ViewController.h

Implementation Files: SettingsVC.m ViewController.m

In ViewController.m, I imported SettingsVC.h using this line of code at the top

import "SettingsVC.h"
so I can obtain a value from a stepper from a different view.

In SettingsVC.h I have a line of code that says IBOutlet UIStepper *mainStepper;

that is assigned to a stepper.

When I try to access the value of the stepper from the ViewController.m by doing this mainStepper.value it doesn't work but it works in the Settings.m Thanks for any help.

New stuff for Vikings

SettingsVC.h FILE

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsVC : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {

IBOutlet UILabel *mainTimeShow;
IBOutlet UILabel *armTimeShow;
IBOutlet UILabel *defuseTimeShow;
IBOutlet UIStepper *armStepper;
IBOutlet UIStepper *defuseStepper;
IBOutlet UIStepper *mainStepper;


}

-(IBAction)goToClock;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIStepper *mainStepper;
-(IBAction)mainTimeStepper;
-(IBAction)armTimeStepper;
-(IBAction)defuseTimeStepper;

@end
```

SettingsVC.m FILE

```
#import "SettingsVC.h"

@interface SettingsVC ()

@end

@implementation SettingsVC

@synthesize mainStepper;

@end
```

ViewController.m FILE

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SettingsVC.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)here {
SettingsVC.mainStepper.value; //Property mainStepper not found on object of type 'SettingsVC'
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you please post complete sections of the relevant files? To format them as code, indent with four spaces.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code.

Comment: I think that's everything relevant. Just need to know how to access mainStepper from the view controller implementation file.

Comment: Is that enough to let you know what is going on or do you need something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my answer, and this should make everything clear.  You only create the UIStepper in one class, in this case SettingsVC.  Then you can retrieve the variable through the property in other classes, just import SettingsVC.

You need to create the property in SettingsVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsVC : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {

// Your other instance variables

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIStepper *mainStepper;

@end
```

You need to synthesize the property in SettingsVC.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SettingsVC.h"

@implementation SettingsVC

@synthesize mainStepper;

@end
```

Let's say you have a class named ViewController.  You would access the value of the UIStepper like such:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SettingsVC.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SettingsVC *settingsVC = [[SettingsVC alloc] init];
    settingsVC.mainStepper.value = 23.0;

    NSLog(@"%f", settingsVC.mainStepper.value);
}

@end
```

You will be using this in other classes, so you need to retain this property.  You typically only use assign with primitive values such as a BOOL.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIStepper *mainStepper;
```

Edit: ARC will will automatically release settingsVC for you, so never explicitly release.

Comment: It doesn't let me synthesize this   (at)property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIStepper *mainStepper;    by doing this       (at)synthesize mainStepper;

Comment: I did what you said and there is an error in the implementation file that says Property implementation must have its declaration            in interface controller. I edited the question to show you the new files. Note that they are two different class files for two different storyboards.

Comment: You must synthesize the property in SettingsVC.m

Comment: It still has a problem, says mainStepper is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: @user1342573 check my recent edit. This should make everything clear.  This is a complete example of how to get the value of the stepper in another class.

Comment: When I do that it claims that mainStepper is not a property of SettingsVC

Comment: Please post your full header file of SettingsVC, so I can look at it.  I'll edit out any information not needed to make it clear.

Comment: I mean I just added the full header,

Comment: @user1342573 check out my edit, you need to retain this so you can use this in other classes

Comment: When it said assign that was some experimenting, it still doesn't work with retain.

Comment: Which class is causing this error, and you are synthesize this stepper at?  Which line is causing the error?

Comment: I'm only synthesizing the stepper in SettingsVC.m, and the only place where there seems to be an error is when I try to access the mainStepper value in an implementation file.

Comment: Edit your question with the code where you are accessing the stepper which is causing the error.  You must import SettingsVC.h in that .m fil

Comment: I edited showed the line thats causing the error in ViewController.m and I did import it in that .m file.

Comment: Ok it got the NSLog to work but the release line says that the ARC forbids the use of release.

Comment: Didn't know you were using ARC, i'm going to edit the code.  You never release if ARC, and the property should be strong.  Check edit.